# UCS2 Hex encoding

Tags: java

I need to send sms msg using a local broker who accepts only UCS2 HEX endcoding.

I've been googling a lot about it, but couldn't find the result

I have a php working example, but i cannot find the solution in JAVA

```
function sms__unicode($message) {
   if (function_exists('iconv')) {
       $latin = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $message);
     if (strcmp($latin, $message)) {
        $arr = unpack('H*hex', @iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE', $message));
        return strtoupper($arr['hex']) .'&unicode=1';
    }
}
return FALSE;
}
```

if I call the PHP function for the hebrew word test ("בדיקה") i get

05D105D305D905E705D4&unicode=1

which is the correct one.

HOW do i get this in JAVA

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since there's little difference between UTF-16 and UCS-2 (UCS-2 is an older standard not supporting supplementary characters, but thankfully Hebrew doesn't have them), you can just use Java's `char` type and encode it using any means available. Something like

```
"בדיקה".chars().mapToObj(c -> String.format("%04X", c)).reduce((s1, s2) -> s1 + s2).orElse("")
```

can do the trick.